# Add Information To XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, insert, addition

Say I have an XML Document that looks like this:

```
 <BOOK>
  <NAME>Home</NAME>
  <ISBN>0-943396-04-2</ISBN>
  <PRICE>$0.82</PRICE>
 </BOOK>
```

And I have a program that has the purpose of allowing the user to add another book to the list... what code would I put on the Button I have titled "Add Book" to make it add another set of information?

So the end product would look like this:

```
 <BOOK>
  <NAME>Home</NAME>
  <ISBN>0-943396-04-2</ISBN>
  <PRICE>$0.82</PRICE>
 </BOOK>
 <BOOK>
  <NAME>Work</NAME>
  <ISBN>0-85131-041-9</ISBN>
  <PRICE>$0.99</PRICE>
 </BOOK>
```

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

firstly youll need to put a container around your books list so

```
<BOOKS>
<BOOK>
  <NAME>Home</NAME>
  <ISBN>0-943396-04-2</ISBN>
  <PRICE>$0.82</PRICE>
 </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

Then you'll need to parse it with something are you storing it in a file? if so then

```
XElement.Load(filename);
```

otherwise you can parse a string

```
XElement el = XElement.Parse(@"<BOOKS><BOOK>
  <NAME>Home</NAME>
  <ISBN>0-943396-04-2</ISBN>
  <PRICE>$0.82</PRICE>
 </BOOK></BOOKS>");
```

then create a and add a new book

```
var newBook = new XElement("BOOK", new[]
{ 
    new XElement("NAME", "thename"), 
    new XElement("ISBN", "isbn"), 
    new XElement("PRICE", ".71") 
});
el.Add(newBook);
```

and save it if you need to

```
el.Save(filename)
```

Reformatted comment below;

```
var el = XElement.Load("Ops.xml");
var newOp = new XElement("Operation", new[] {
    new XElement("Operation Name", textBox2.Text), 
    new XElement("Operation Date", dateTimePicker1.Value)
});
el.Add(newOp);
```

Comment: So, where "thename" is can I put textbox1.Text ?

Comment: yeah put your variables into the second parameter of the XElement constructor.

Comment: 'System.Xml.XmlElement' does not contain a definition for 'Load'

Comment: Wrong namespace and class you are after System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Comment: I added using System.Xml.Linq.XElement to the list. However XElement is not going Blue...

Comment: change the using to `System.Xml.Linq` you'll need to make sure you have a reference to System.Xml.Linq in your references, under the project node in solution explorer.

Comment: I fixed the issue with XElement but it says el does not exist.

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
           XElement.Load("Ops.xml");
            var newOp = new XElement("Operation" new []
            {
                new XElement("Operation Name", textBox2.Text);
                new XElement("Operation Date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
           });
          el.Add(newOp);
        }
is what it looks like, and I am getting errors saying there is {,},(, or ) symbols expected on each line.

Comment: updated my answer with a reformat of your method from the comment.

Comment: Ok, so I have Ops.xml with my Program, but putting Ops.xml does not update it. And putting the path gets all sorts of Unrecognized Escape Sequence errors.

Comment: This pops up next to the first line "'>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 1, position 65." ... there is no >

Comment: seems like you have some malformed xml. Are you able to add your xml to the question?